# google maps circle overlay - fixed size on zoom in and zoom out of the map

Tags: google-maps, overlay, zooming

I'm trying to add a circle overlay to a map, but I have to make the circle to stay the same size if a user zooms in or out of the map 
The below code shows how I am displaying the circle on the map

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Circles</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
       var citymap = [
        {
            center: {lat:21.176801, lng: 72.832036}
        }
    ];
    var gmarkers = [];
    var markers = [{
        "title": 'point1',
        "lat": '21.17700',
        "lng": '72.8321000',
        "description": 'uuu'
    }];

    function initMap() {
        // Create the map.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 14,
            center: {lat:21.176801, lng: 72.832036},
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            styles: [
                {
                    "featureType": "poi",
                    "stylers": [
                        { "visibility": "off" }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var lat_lng = new Array();
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                icon:'peoples_Notif.png',
                title: data.title
            });
            latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
            (function(marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.title);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });

            })(marker, data);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                map.setZoom(8);
            });
            gmarkers.push(marker);
        }
        map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());

        // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
        //scale circle based on the radius
        for (var i=0;i<citymap.length;i++) {
            var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
                strokeColor: '#FFD700',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#FFD700',
                fillOpacity: 1.0,
                map: map,
                center: citymap[i].center,
                radius:200
            });

        }
    }

</script>
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkkS2pZmOgryjc3ZX0sE5Q8tIdsm-Ged4&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
<script src="https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

can any say is there a option where I can enable or how to go about it

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of options:

1. add a `zoom_changed` listener to the map and resize your circles dynamically depending on the zoom level (each zoom level is a factor of 2 different)
2. use a circular marker for the circle, an SVG Symbol seems to work:

   ```
   var cityCircleM = new google.maps.Marker({
       map: map,
       position: citymap[i].center,
       title: "circle",
       icon: {
         strokeColor: '#FFD700',
         strokeOpacity: 1.0,
         strokeWeight: 2,
         fillColor: '#FFD700',
         fillOpacity: 1.0,
         path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
         scale: 20,
         anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
       },
       zIndex: Math.round(citymap[i].center.lat * -100000) << 5

     });
   ```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/h5ycxytt/5/)